# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in .../test6_2.php on line 20

Tags: php, reference, operators

Just trying to save and fix sources from [PHPBench.com](http://phpbench.com)

and hit this error (the site is down and the author didn't respond to questions). This is the source:

```
<?php

// Initial Configuration
class SomeClass {
  function f() {

  }
}
$i = 0; //fix for Notice: Undefined variable i error

// Test Source
function Test6_2() {
  //global $aHash; //we don't need that in this test
  global $i; //fix for Notice: Undefined variable i error

  /* The Test */
  $t = microtime(true);
  while($i < 1000) {
    $obj =& new SomeClass();
    ++$i;
  }

  usleep(100); //sleep or you'll return 0 microseconds at every run!!!
  return (microtime(true) - $t);
}

?>
```

Is it a valid syntax or not? Correct me if I'm wrong but think it creates a reference to SomeClass, so we can call `new $obj()` ... Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: `=& new ...` is an invalid syntax

Comment: The class instance needs to be assigned to a variable, so you have to assign the instance to a variable and then put the reference to the variable to `$obj`, but my question is, why do you need a reference?

Comment: This is the test - comparison between `= new` and `=& new` when creating a new object

Comment: The syntax is since `PHP 5.0` deprecated and got removed in `PHP 7.0`. `PHP 5.0` says `Strict Standards: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated` https://3v4l.org/AKH8r

Comment: Well, it's weird why PHP7 installation won't output when something is deprecated. Are they removed that in `error_reporting(-1)` mode in scripts and ~E_DEPRECATED added next to E_ALL in php.ini?

Comment: The syntax got **removed** in PHP7.

Comment: IDEs supporting PHP should display those errors, right? The problem is that I'm with notepad++

Comment: I don't use one for PHP, so I can't say for sure. But probably most IDEs won't show that since the syntax can still be used in PHP 5.5 and 5.6 (5.5 reached recently end of life, but 5.6 is still supported).

Comment: I use PhpStorm when I code in PHP, and it does have a feature to review your code for deprecated stuff. But since the `=&` syntax has been deprecated since 5.0 (circa 2004), it's hard to understand what made you think it would do anything useful.

Comment: As I stated that's a code from an already non-active site :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Objects are always stored by reference anyway. You don't need `=&` and as Charlotte commented, it's deprecated syntax.

> Correct me if I'm wrong but think it creates a reference to SomeClass, so we can call new $obj() .

No, this is not correct. The `new` operator always creates an instance of the class, not a reference to the class as a type.

You can create a variable object instantiation simply by creating a *string* variable with the name of the class, and using that.

```
$class = "MyClass";
$obj = new $class();
```

Functions like [get_class()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) or [ReflectionClass::getName()](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getname.php) return the class name as a string. There is no "reference to the class" concept in PHP like there is in Java.

The closest thing you're thinking of is [ReflectionClass::newInstance()](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstance.php) but this is an unnecessary way of creating an object dynamically. In almost every case, it's better to just use `new $class()`.

Comment: Is it better to use more memory for defining string variables when speaking about microbenchmarks?

Comment: Better than what? Not defining string variables? It's just a scalar. If your code is so sensitive to performance that using a string variable is a deal-breaker, then you probably shouldn't be using PHP in the first place.